# How can I pass default credentials to a PowerShell Web Client Object? Alternative to Invoke-WebRequest for PS v2?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, webclient

I'm running the following code

```
$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadFile( $UriValue, "C:\Temp\BHRout.json" )
$json = Get-Content "C:\Temp\BHRout.json"
```

This does not work because it needs my prompts credentials passed into the download string function. I've used the above code to replace this:

```
$NagiosResults = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -UseDefaultCredentials | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The only problem with this is that the server I'm running the script on doesn't have Powershell v3; so this will not work either. Is there an alternative to `Invoke-WebRequest` for Powershell v2? If not, is there a way to 'use default credentials' with a System.Net.WebClient object?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just set the [`UseDefaultCredentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.usedefaultcredentials.aspx) property of the WebClient to `$true` and that will use the credentials of the current user for authentication.

```
$uri = "http://myserver/service"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$json = $wc.DownloadString($uri)
```