# Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, authentication, sharepoint

I want to authenticate to sharepoint using PowerShell v7

and I'm using this command with attributes URL site and Credentials for Sharepoint

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred
```

to authenticate to SharePoint.

But I got this error even my account without MFA:

[image: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password using PowerShell 7]

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory. How did you construct the `$cred` object?

Comment: Could also be that you're using the wrong module. Are you using the new `PnP.PowerShell` module or the old `SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline`?

Comment: Use default credentials : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882853/how-can-i-pass-default-credentials-to-a-powershell-web-client-object-alternativ

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen by  $Cred = Get-Credential

Comment: @ThomasGlaser I install the new module which is PnP.PowerShell

Comment: Can you please post code as text rather than an image - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors for more details...

Comment: @mclayton yes ofc :                                                                                           
$SiteURL = "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/"
$Cred = Get-Credential
  
Try {
 
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred

}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can try this PnP Powershell:

```
$SiteURL="https://Crescent.sharepoint.com"
$UserName="Salaudeen@thecrescenttech.com"
$Password = "password"
 
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, $SecurePassword
 
#connect to sharepoint online site using powershell
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred
```

Reference:
[Connect to SharePoint Online using PnP PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/connect-to-sharepoint-online-using-pnp-powershell.html#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Connect%20to%20SharePoint%20Online%20using%20PnP,2%3A%20Connect%20to%20SharePoint%20Online%20using%20PnP%20PowerShell)