# Why is my Password notification script not sending the email?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, active-directory, smtp-auth

I have this script and when i run it runs fine find the users and when they are about to be email the script try to send but it errors out: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: Authentication required

```
  <# 
.Synopsis 
   Script to Automated Email Reminders when Users Passwords due to Expire. 
   Modified for company Inc.
.DESCRIPTION 
   Script to Automated Email Reminders when Users Passwords due to Expire. 
   Robert Pearman (Cloud & Data Center MVP) 
   WindowsServerEssentials.com 
   Version 2.3 March 2017 (There is no support for this version)
   Requires: Windows PowerShell Module for Active Directory 
   
.EXAMPLE
  PasswordChangeNotification.ps1 -smtpServer smtpaws.com -expireInDays 7 -from "noreply@domain.com <noreply@domain.com>" -Logging -LogPath "C:\Scripts\ExpPass Notification\Logs\" -testing -testRecipient user@domain.com
.EXAMPLE 
  PasswordChangeNotification.ps1 -smtpServer mail.domain.com -expireInDays 21 -from "IT Support <support@domain.com>" -Logging -LogPath "c:\logFiles" -testing -testRecipient support@domain.com 
.EXAMPLE 
  PasswordChangeNotification.ps1 -smtpServer mail.domain.com -expireInDays 21 -from "IT Support <support@domain.com>"  
#> 

param (
    # $smtpServer Enter Your SMTP Server Hostname or IP Address 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 0)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [string]$smtpServer,
    
    # Notify Users if Expiry Less than X Days 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 1)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [int]$expireInDays,

    # From Address, eg "IT Support <support@domain.com>" 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True, Position = 2)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [string]$from,

    # Log File Path
    [Parameter(Position = 3)]
    [switch]$logging,

    [Parameter(Position = 4)]
    [string]$logPath,

    # Testing Enabled 
    [Parameter(Position = 5)]
    [switch]$testing,

    # Test Recipient, eg recipient@domain.com 
    [Parameter(Position = 6)]
    [string]$testRecipient,

    [Parameter(Position = 7)]
    [switch]$status,

    [Parameter(Position = 8)]
    [int]$skipNotificationDay = 0,

    [Parameter(Position = 9)]
    [string]$adSearchGroup = 'EveryoneDL'

)
#SMTP Credentials
    $smtpuser = "username"
    $smtppass = "C:\Scripts\username.cred"
    $smtpcred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $smtpuser, (Get-Content $smtppass | ConvertTo-SecureString)
################################################################################################################### 
$start = [datetime]::Now
$midnight = $start.Date.AddDays(1)
$timeToMidnight = New-TimeSpan -Start $start -end $midnight.Date
$midnight2 = $start.Date.AddDays(2)
$timeToMidnight2 = New-TimeSpan -Start $start -end $midnight2.Date
# System Settings 
$textEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$today = $start
# End System Settings 

# Get Users From AD who are Enabled, Passwords Expire and are Not Currently Expired 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$padVal = "20"
Write-Output "Script Loaded"
Write-Output "*** Settings Summary ***"
$smtpServerLabel = "SMTP Server".PadRight($padVal, " ")
$expireInDaysLabel = "Expire in Days".PadRight($padVal, " ")
$fromLabel = "From".PadRight($padVal, " ")
$testLabel = "Testing".PadRight($padVal, " ")
$testRecipientLabel = "Test Recipient".PadRight($padVal, " ")
$logLabel = "Logging".PadRight($padVal, " ")
$logPathLabel = "Log Path".PadRight($padVal, " ")
if ($testing)
{
    if (($testRecipient) -eq $null)
    {
        Write-Output "No Test Recipient Specified"
        Exit
    }
}
if ($logging)
{
    if (($logPath) -eq $null)
    {
        $logPath = $PSScriptRoot
    }
}
Write-Output "$smtpServerLabel : $smtpServer"
Write-Output "$expireInDaysLabel : $expireInDays"
Write-Output "$fromLabel : $from"
Write-Output "$logLabel : $logging"
Write-Output "$logPathLabel : $logPath"
Write-Output "$testLabel : $testing"
Write-Output "$testRecipientLabel : $testRecipient"
Write-Output "*".PadRight(25, "*")


# Original User qualification, searched all users in domain
# $users = get-aduser -filter { (Enabled -eq $true) -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false) } -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress | where { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false }
# Filter User Qualification By Group - Added by user
$group = Get-ADGroup -Identity $adSearchGroup
$users = get-aduser -filter { (Enabled -eq $true) -and (PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false) -and ( memberOf -eq $group.DistinguishedName) } -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress | where { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false }

# Count Users 
$usersCount = ($users | Measure-Object).Count
Write-Output "Found $usersCount User Objects"
# Collect Domain Password Policy Information 
$defaultMaxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy -ErrorAction Stop).MaxPasswordAge.Days
Write-Output "Domain Default Password Age: $defaultMaxPasswordAge"
# Collect Users 
$colUsers = @()
# Process Each User for Password Expiry 
Write-Output "Process User Objects"
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    $Name = $user.Name
    $emailaddress = $user.emailaddress
    $passwordSetDate = $user.PasswordLastSet
    $samAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
    $pwdLastSet = $user.PasswordLastSet
    # Check for Fine Grained Password 
    $maxPasswordAge = $defaultMaxPasswordAge
    $PasswordPol = (Get-AduserResultantPasswordPolicy $user)
    if (($PasswordPol) -ne $null)
    {
        $maxPasswordAge = ($PasswordPol).MaxPasswordAge.Days
    }
    # Create User Object 
    $userObj = New-Object System.Object
    $expireson = $pwdLastSet.AddDays($maxPasswordAge)
    $daysToExpire = New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $Expireson
    # Round Up or Down 
    if (($daysToExpire.Days -eq "0") -and ($daysToExpire.TotalHours -le $timeToMidnight.TotalHours))
    {
        $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name UserMessage -Value "today."
    }
    if (($daysToExpire.Days -eq "0") -and ($daysToExpire.TotalHours -gt $timeToMidnight.TotalHours) -or ($daysToExpire.Days -eq "1") -and ($daysToExpire.TotalHours -le $timeToMidnight2.TotalHours))
    {
        $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name UserMessage -Value "tomorrow."
    }
    if (($daysToExpire.Days -ge "1") -and ($daysToExpire.TotalHours -gt $timeToMidnight2.TotalHours))
    {
        $days = $daysToExpire.TotalDays
        $days = [math]::Round($days)
        $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name UserMessage -Value "in $days days."
    }
    $daysToExpire = [math]::Round($daysToExpire.TotalDays)
    $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name UserName -Value $samAccountName
    $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Name
    $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name EmailAddress -Value $emailAddress
    $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name PasswordSet -Value $pwdLastSet
    $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name DaysToExpire -Value $daysToExpire
    $userObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name ExpiresOn -Value $expiresOn
    
    # Exclude this user from processing if the number of days to expiration equals the value
    if ( $daysToExpire -ne $skipNotificationDay )
    {
        $colUsers += $userObj
    }
}
$colUsersCount = ($colUsers | Measure-Object).Count
Write-Output "$colusersCount Users processed"
$notifyUsers = $colUsers | where { $_.DaysToExpire -le $expireInDays }
$notifiedUsers = @()
$notifyCount = ($notifyUsers | Measure-Object).Count
Write-Output "$notifyCount Users to notify"
foreach ($user in $notifyUsers)
{
    # Email Address 
    $samAccountName = $user.UserName
    $emailAddress = $user.EmailAddress
    # Set Greeting Message 
    $name = $user.Name
    $messageDays = $user.UserMessage
    # Subject Setting 
    $subject = "Your password will expire $messageDays"
    # Email Body Set Here, Note You can use HTML, including Images. 
    $body = " 
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Dear $name,</p>
    <p>In line with our security policies, your  network account password is expiring $messageDays If you do not change your password before it expires, you will be unable to access your email and/or computer.</p>
    <p><span style='color: #ff0000;'>What do I do next?</span></p>
    <p><strong>For PC:</strong>&nbsp;</p>
    <ol>
    <li>If you are working remotely, please connect over VPN.</li>
    <li>Press <em>CTRL + ALT + Delete</em> and choose <em>Change Password</em>.</li>
    </ol>
    <p><strong>For Mac:</strong></p>
    <ol>
    <li>From the top right corner of your monitor click the icon with the company <span style='color: #ff0000;'>f</span> and select <em>Change Password</em>. This will prompt the OKTA Authentication.</li>
    <li>Click <em>Edit Profile</em>, provide authentication, and follow through with the workflow until the password has changed.</li>
    <li>Once the password is changed, click done and provide the Local Mac Password for synchronization. Unless your passwords haven&rsquo;t synchronized before, the Local Mac Password should be your old password. </li>
    </ol>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Thank you for your quick action on this matter, <br />company | IT Department.</p>"
    
    # If Testing Is Enabled - Email Administrator 
    if ($testing)
    {
        $emailaddress = $testRecipient
    } # End Testing 
    
    # If a user has no email address listed 
    if (($emailaddress) -eq $null)
    {
        $emailaddress = $testRecipient
    } # End No Valid Email 
    $samLabel = $samAccountName.PadRight($padVal, " ")
    if ($status)
    {
        Write-Output "Sending Email : $samLabel : $emailAddress"
    }
    try
    {
        Send-Mailmessage -smtpServer $smtpServer -Credential $smtpcred -UseSsl -from $from -to $emailaddress -subject $subject -body $body -bodyasHTML -priority High -Encoding $textEncoding -ErrorAction Stop
        $user | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SendMail -Value "OK"
    }
    catch
    {
        $errorMessage = $_.exception.Message
        if ($status)
        {
            $errorMessage
        }
        $user | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SendMail -Value $errorMessage
    }
    $notifiedUsers += $user
}
if ($logging)
{
    # Create Log File 
    Write-Output "Creating Log File"
    $day = $today.Day
    $month = $today.Month
    $year = $today.Year
    $date = "$day-$month-$year"
    $logFileName = "$date-PasswordLog.csv"
    if (!($logPath.EndsWith("\")))
    {
        $logFile = $logPath + "\"
    }
    $logFile = $logFile + $logFileName
    Write-Output "Log Output: $logfile"
    $notifiedUsers | Export-CSV $logFile
}
$notifiedUsers | select UserName, Name, EmailAddress, PasswordSet, DaysToExpire, ExpiresOn | sort DaystoExpire | FT -autoSize


$stop = [datetime]::Now
$runTime = New-TimeSpan $start $stop
Write-Output "Script Runtime: $runtime"
# End
```

i tried:

PasswordChangeNotification.ps1 -smtpServer smtpaws.com -expireInDays 7 -from "noreply@domain.com noreply@domain.com" -Logging -LogPath "C:\Scripts\Logs" -testing -testRecipient user@domain.com

it runs but it doesnt send the emails.

Comment: Are you running it using the same user account as the one that originally exported `"C:\Scripts\username.cred"`? And are you sure the cred file contains only a serialized securestring, not a whole credential object?

Comment: Some servers do not accept a credential with username and password and you must use default credentials.  The password is not encrypted with username/password while default credentials the password is encrypted.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen What do you mean i use the same username as when you create the exported file it ask you for the username and password. i am wondering if I need to do anything in specific?

Comment: @jdweng Do you mean to only encrypt the password? How can I Do that it always ask me for both.

Comment: Presumably you (or someone else) ran some code akin to `("password" |ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlaintext) |ConvertFrom-SecureString |Set-Content C:\Scripts\username.cred` at some point in time. Whatever user account was used to run that code is the only user that can successfully decrypt the value by piping it to `ConvertTo-SecureString` again. So, is that the same user account as the one you're currently testing the script with? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes it is the same account, I created a service account to run this task everyday.

Comment: Then you're gonna have to show us how you created the credential file :)

Comment: the credential file was created using administrator Powershell: for example I ran $credential = Get-Credential once it ask me the windows to enter the username and password then I ran ---> to save
$credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content "C:\Scripts\smtp.credentials"

Comment: Get default credentials : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882853/how-can-i-pass-default-credentials-to-a-powershell-web-client-object-alternativ

Comment: @jdweng where should i place the code for the default credentials?

Comment: It should replace the following line and will use the credential of the user that is running code instead of you specifying the user : $smtpcred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $smtpuser, (Get-Content $smtppass | ConvertTo-SecureString)

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by using the protocol TSL if you add the following to the code it will work:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```