# Powershell 7 Connect-PnPOnline throw error - Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.Internal.NullScope' in VS Code

Tags: powershell

When executing 'Connect-PnpOnline' with the following parameters (see below) an error is thrown in VS code. When I execute the same code in the powershel 7 command promd then it works. The issue is when I open same powershell file in VS to debug then it throw the errors. Any help much appreciated. I have installed below modules to connect to PnP.

PowerShell Version - 7.3.9
Command Executed to Connect to PnP - Install-Module PnP.PowerShell -RequiredVersion 1.12 -Force.

PFB the Code-

```
$user = "admin@test.com"
  $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "test@123" -AsPlainText -Force
  $psCred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList($user, $pass)
  Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://sharepoint.com" -Credentials $psCred
```

Error:
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.Internal.NullScope' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Comment: Try default credentials instead of username/password.   Most systems reject username/password because the password is not encrypted.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882853/how-can-i-pass-default-credentials-to-a-powershell-web-client-object-alternativ

Comment: @jdweng URL is protected I have to pass service account to access it.